# Не понимаю,почему не происходит вывод?

Tags: python

```
N = int(input())
a = []
for i in range (N):
    a.append(int(input()))

p = []

for j in a:
    j = str(j)
    if j == reversed(j):
        j = int(j)
        p.append (j)

print(max(p))
```

***Задача:***Тогда Маша подумала, что даже при фиксированном направлении письма запись некоторых чисел — например, 616 или 4224, — не зависит от того, с младших или со старших разрядов их начинать записывать. Интересно, а как часто встречаются такие числа-палиндромы?
Формат входных данных
В единственной строке записано натуральное число `N <= 100000.`
Формат выходных данных:
Выведите N-ое в порядке возрастания число среди всех натуральных чисел, являющихся
палиндромами в десятичной записи. Нумерация начинается с единицы.
Пример
стандартный поток ввода, стандартный поток вывода:

```
21 121
```

Comment: Уууууу, всош по инфе... мне кажется, тебя убьют за такое

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`reverse` возвращает не строку, её можно сделать так:

```
 if j == "".join(reversed(j))
```

А короче будет запись с использованием среза

```
 if j == j[::-1]
```

И вообще откуда берётся ввод `a[]`??

```
N = int(input())
c = 0
i = 0

while c < N:
    i += 1
    j = str(i)
    if j == j[::-1]:
        p = int(j)
        c += 1

print(p)
```